# Modelo Entidad Relación de un directorio telefónico

Tags: base-de-datos

Estoy haciendo un MER de un directorio telefónico, el cual lleva una entidad usuario para hacer un logIn, una entidad amigos, familia y trabajo, las cuales llevan un id y un nombre del grupo como atributos y una entidad contacto, el cual lleva como atributos toda la info de un contacto.
¿Está bien este modelo? Obviamente me falta añadir los atributos, pero ¿Está bien representado?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Me sumo a los demás en que `Contactos` tiene `Tipos` que serian `Amigos`, `Familiares` y `Trabajo`. Y puedo aportarte en que siempre las entidades se llaman con *Mayúsculas* y los atributos en *Minúsculas*.

Answer (score 1):

Yo te recomendaría que lo formules de la siguiente manera

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto pues, un usuario tiene una lista de contactos, esos contactos tienes un tipo, que puede ser un familiar, un amigo, trabajo. Pero te expongo la siguiente situación: que pasaría si después quieres agregar el tipo pendiente (para usuarios que no sepas quien es, pero no lo quieres eliminar), también agregar tipo BlackList, además contacto de colegio y todos los tipos que quieras, tendrías que crear muchas más entidades; mientras que de esta forma ya tienes un contacto que tiene un tipo.

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que la entidad `Contacto` tiene la información común (los atributos comunes) a `Trabajo`, `Familiares` y `Amigos`.

Por lo tanto, visto desde este punto de vista, haría que la entidad `Contacto` fuera común para los tres tipos de `Contactos` que puedes tener (`Trabajo`, `Familiares`, `Amigos`) con los atributos comunes a los tres y estos heredaran los atributos comunes desde esta entidad `Contacto`.

Posteriormente, en cada entidad solo tendrías que poner los atributos específicos para cada entidad.

Quedaría algo así:

```
         USUARIO
           |
           |
    Añade, borra y/o
         cambia
           |
           |
        CONTACTO
          /|\
   Trabajo | Amigos
       Familiares
```